# Best tcp send buffer size

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

What is the best tcp send buffer size? For example I want to send a big file (10-100MB) and I set buffer size to 4Kb, but what is the best buffer size for that?

Comment: There's no one correct answer but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/42258274/1076479

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Come off it. This is not a 'request for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, [or] code'. It is a simple question about a number, and it has been asked here many times before. Your comment is ridiculous.

Comment: @GilHamilton The bandwidth-delay product is the one correct answer.

Comment: @EJP That would apply at the network layer in a perfect network for one pair of endpoints, but the application is generally far removed from that and its `send` call does not map 1-to-1 to a packet. I'm quite sure I can "fill the pipe" by writing 1K bytes at a time as easily as 1M bytes. The OS will still send MTU-byte packets up to the limit given by the receive window. The OS will also allow me to stuff more data into its own local buffers up to some point well above what can be sent in the receive window. This is explained informally in the question I linked to above.

Comment: @GilHamilton The question is not about how much you write at a time. The question is about the size of the send buffer, and the answer is given by the bandwidth-delay product. Anything less prevents you from filling the pipe; anything more is wasteful. The OS cannot fill the pipe unless it can hold the entire receive window, given by the receiver's socket receive buffer, in the socket send buffer.

Comment: @EJP I believe you are misinterpreting OP's use of the ambiguous term "tcp send buffer". My take is that OP is writing an application, connecting a *socket* (hence the tag) to a remote endpoint via TCP and *is* in fact asking about the buffer size to use for the application `send` call.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to send a big file (10-100MB) and I set buffer size to 4Kb, but what is the best buffer size for that?

Certainly not 4Kb. At least 32-48Kb, or 64Kb or more if you can afford it. In general it should be at least equal to the bandwidth-delay product of the network path, so that you 'fill the pipe' and make maximum use of the available bandwidth.

If you're in control of the other end you should also set its socket *receive* buffer to a similar size.